# how to parse the byte array of type datetime(3) in the binlog of mysql5.5

Tags: java, mysql-5.5

how to parse the byte array of type datetime(3)  in the binlog of mysql5.5;
i have known the length of the byte array of type datetime(3) is 8, but i don't know how to parse it to Timestamp

the way to parse the byte array to Timestamp

Comment: You don't "parse the byte array" at all. What you do is issue your select query then get the appropriate date column from the `ResultSet`. `getTimestamp(int)` will do that for you but it might be better to use a class from `java.time`

Comment: i am trying to develop a software to subscribe the binlog of mysql, as a replica of a mysql, so my question is to parse the data of type datetime(3) in the binlog

Comment: Ah I see sorry. I think I'd need to look at an example binlog file

Comment: afaics they are in Unix time (seconds since the epoch) so for string timestamp 's': `Instant i = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.valueOf(s));`

Comment: @gee Please [edit] your question to include the binlog format you are using. Also [edit] your question to include the source code you have so far.

Comment: i used mariadb which version is '5.5.64-MariaDB-1~trusty', i get the method to parse the byte array of type datetime(3) after test,  it is different with the datetime type;

Comment: the byte array of the type datetime(3) you get through subscribing the binlog is the micros from the time 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000

Comment: No, afaics microseconds would be datatime(6). datetime(3) is milliseconds